# How can I add Signature Pad to my Rails App?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to add a signature pad field (from: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) in my Rails app but I have no idea how to implement it for MVC file structure in a Rails app. I don't even want to use a rails form, just html for this particular use case but I just CANNOT get the JS to work and it's incredibly frustrating.

I don't understand the documentation after the installation process via yarn. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install this by adding it to `package.json`. `package.json` is to Node what `Gemfile` is to Ruby.

Comment: Add what? Which part of the code from the wiki are you referring to?

Comment: I'm wondering how to do this with Rails 7 & import maps

Comment: hey @SheriTibbs I ended up wasting too much time on this and opted for having a simple checkbox with copy similar to "I agree to the terms and conditions". I know this doesn't answer how to implement it, but it was the best solution for me.

If you're still really wanting to - I found that Tressa Sanders had more success with the John Hancock gem: https://github.com/Brantron/john_hancock

Here's the guide: https://tressa-sanders.medium.com/adding-signature-signing-to-my-ruby-on-rails-app-with-signature-pad-7451a6dc508d